# Nested repeater not being triggered

Tags: c#, .net

I have three repeaters with a parent child relationship (so we have a parent repeater, and child repeater, and a child-child repeater) with the inner-most repeater not being triggered.  here is my aspx page for the layout:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMission" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
<ul id="acc1" class="ui-accordion-container">
</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
<li>
    <div class="ui-accordion-left"></div>
    <a class="ui-accordion-link acc1"><%# Eval("Name") %><span class="ui-accordion-right"></span></a>
    <div>
        <ul class="ui-accordion-container" id="acc2">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptActivity" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <div class="ui-accordion-left"></div>
                <a class="ui-accordion-link acc2"><%# Eval("Name") %>
                <span class="ui-accordion-right"></span></a>
                <div>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptProject" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Name") %><br/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</ul>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The top two repeaters work great but the 'rptProject' repeater doesn't get triggered.  Here is my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _presenter = new TierTypesPresenter(this);
        rptMission.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptMission_ItemDataBound);

        RaiseStartUp();
    }

    void rptMission_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        Mission row = (Mission)item.DataItem;
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var rptActivity = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptActivity");
            var activity = _presenter.GetActivitiesByMission(row.Id);
            rptActivity.DataSource = activity;
            rptActivity.DataBind();
        }
    }

    void rptActivity_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        Activity row = (Activity)item.DataItem;
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var rptProject = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptProject");
            var project = _presenter.GetProjectsByActivities(row.Id);
            rptProject.DataSource = project;
            rptProject.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public void SetMissions(IEnumerable<Mission> missionList)
    {
        rptMission.DataSource = missionList;
        rptMission.DataBind();
    }
```

If I could trigger the second ItemDataBound event 'rptActivity_ItemDataBound' I think it would work fine but it gets skipped over.  Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by putting the third repeater binding into the second repeaters ItemBoundEvent.  Here is the updated code for any interested:

```
void rptMission_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        Mission row = (Mission)item.DataItem;
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var rptActivity = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptActivity");
            var activity = _presenter.GetActivitiesByMission(row.Id);
            var i = 0;
            foreach (Activity data in activity)
            {
                RepeaterItem activityItem = rptActivity.Items[i];
                var rptProject = (Repeater)activityItem.FindControl("rptProject");
                var project = _presenter.GetProjectsByActivities(data.Id);
                rptProject.DataSource = project;
                rptProject.DataBind();
                i++;
            }
            rptActivity.DataSource = activity;
            rptActivity.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing this line of code:

```
rptActivity .ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptActivity_ItemDataBound);
```

It is easier to set the events in the asp file by the way...

Comment: I received an 'reference not set to instance of object' error.

Comment: I set the OnDataBound event in the rptActivty control to rptActivity_ItemDataBound but I'm getting an error saying it does not contain a definition for it.  Thoughts?

Comment: @negzero7 that is because your rptActivity_ItemDataBound is private. Make it protected and it will work. Mhd. Yasseen answer is the way to go. You shouldn't be stuffing code in the same handler.

Comment: I would prefer to separate it out, but even setting it to protected doesn't work.  I believe the reason is that because this is a nested repeater, there will be multiple repeater and you have to specify which one you are setting the Event Handler for.  Putting it in the foreach loop allows me to target each one.